# What is the transaction ID?

Tags: blockchain.info, transaction-id

I have sent a Bitcoin amount to someone who wants the transaction ID. What is this? Is it the hash shown on the LHS of the transaction?

Comment: What client software are you using?

Comment: I do not know what you mean by "client software" but for what it is worth I am using the blockchain wallet system.

Comment: Via the website, the mobile app, or something else?

Comment: via the website

Answer (score 4):

Transaction ID usually refers to the [2xSHA256 hash](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_specification#Hashes) of the transaction serialized as it would have been transferred in the network. This is also the ID as peers [refer to them](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_specification#Inventory_Vectors) when broadcasting through the network.

Notice that due to [transaction malleability](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction_Malleability) a transaction may have multiple IDs.